# Automatically propagating changes to a list view to web parts

Tags: 2013, web-part, list-view

My list has a view that is used in multiple List View Web Parts throughout my site. Normally, if a change is made to this view, I have to manually update each associated List View Web Part to reference the view once more, as the Web Parts do not stay synced to this view, instead having their own "Current View" that gets updated every time I select the view I want it to have.

This is a pain. Is there any way to configure these web parts to stay "synced" to my view so that changes to it are automatically propagated to the web parts without any need for manual intervention on my part? I'd prefer an out-of-the-box solution but I'd be happy to know of any possible option.